# on data.put() i need to display to the user that the data has been successfully submitted or failure incase pof one

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, jinja2

am using python and google app engine majorly on jinja2 templates
i could like when a user registers a new account, they get a popup indicating that their registration is successful of even any alert on the very interface before moving to the next registration step.

```
def post(self):

            user = (str(users.get_current_user().email()))
            userquery = Users.query(Users.email == user)
            count = userquery.count()
            if count == 0:
                #test if user is admin or employee
                qry = Users.query()
                count = qry.count()
                if count == 0:
                    privilage = 'admin'
                    db_put = Users(
                    f_name=self.request.get("f_name"),
                    l_name = self.request.get("l_name"),
                    org = self.request.get("org"),
                    email=users.get_current_user().email(),
                    privilage = privilage
                                           )
                    db_put.put()
```

Comment: show what you tried and not working.

Comment: print "registration success" but doesnt work, self.response.write( ) also doesn't work since am using templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you calling this POST method? Are you sending a form there directly (use method 1) or is this being done with an AJAX call (use method 2)?

### Method 1

You can redirect to a GET page where you render a template with a success or error message for Jinja to use. This would however involve a page change.

```
import webapp2

class MyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

  def get(self):  # Let's assume /someurl is mapped to this handler.
    template_values = {}
    notification = self.request.get('notification')
    if notification:
      template_values['notification'] = notification
    self.response.set_status(200)
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
    # Need to get the template from jinja and set it as template variable.
    self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

  def post(self):
    # Do all your stuff here.
    self.redirect('/someurl?notification=Success')
```

Alternatively you can set the parameters directly on the request instead of passing them as URI parameters:

```
  def post(self):
    # Do all your stuff here.
    self.redirect('/someurl, params={'notification': 'Success'})
```

### Method 2

In this method you can send back a JSON response with a success or error message. The caller (whatever function in your javascript that submitted the request to the backend) can use that to render a butterbar message or other popup notification of your choosing:

```
import json
import webapp2

class MyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

  def post(self):
    # Do all your stuff here.
    self.response.set_status(200)
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment'
    self.response.out.write(json.JsonEncoder(sort_keys=True).encode('Success'))
```

For the latter, make sure you think about cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities and perhaps add a JSON prefix.

Comment: Am very greatful @sas this worked perfectly thanks for taking your time to understand my problem and solve it

Comment: def post(self):
    # Do all your stuff here.
    self.redirect('/someurl?notification=Success')                                                           this here worked for me

Comment: By the way, if you don't want the notification to be part of the URL, you can also set that parameter directly:  `self.redirect('/someurl, params={'notification': 'Success'})`